# Secure communication between Chrome extension and mobile over local network

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a mobile application and a corresponding chrome extension and planning to use UDP for data communication between mobile and extension using the [udp API provided in chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp)

It seems there is no provision to use DTLS in chrome APIs , so I a wondering how to secure the communication.

If I decide TCP over UDP I think TLS can be used for security as per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp#method-secure)

The mobile app and extension communicate only over local network.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with: **Extensions** cannot use `sockets` APIs. Just so that doesn't come as a shock later. Only **Apps** have access to that.

That said, the `sockets` API provide you access to raw sockets. That means you can implement your own security on top of it. The API method you quote is there for convenience, but it can be reimplemented.

Comment: I think extensions can use socket APIs.I used the socket APIs in my test extension to receive data from my mobile over the network by registering the callback through chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener().So there is no built-in popular security method and I need to use my own encryption?

Comment: I guess you _think_ you're making an extension when in fact it's an app. No, there are no built-in methods.